# What is the meaning of this Rancher error message: "Error with the container log scanner."

Tags: rancher

We are trying to debug why a Rancher agent became disconnected from the Rancher server, which is on a separate machine.

What is the meaning of this Rancher error message:

```
$ docker logs -f rancher-agent
```

returns

```
time="2018-02-27T17:51:52Z" level=error msg="Error with the container log scanner." error="context canceled"
time="2018-02-27T17:56:05Z" level=error msg="Error with the container log scanner." error="context canceled"
time="2018-02-27T18:18:24Z" level=error msg="Error with the container log scanner." error="context canceled"
time="2018-02-27T18:37:51Z" level=error msg="Error writing EOT message." error="write unix @->/var/run/docker.sock: write: broken pipe"
```

Answer (score 1):

“This is an error that Docker throws when tailing a log file that is empty, references: moby/moby#35370 and moby/moby#36305. As it’s recently merged, it will be available in a next Docker version”.

Source: https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/11592